# Using xmlhttp.open async instead of sync

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am using xml http to read a XML file and then do something with it. It works fine when I use sync, setting it to "false" when using .open().

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET",".."+baseRestUrl+restService+"/"+jmxConnection,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var beanRepArray = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beanRepresentation");
```

But when I set it to "`true`", it always says `xmlDoc is not defined`.

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET",".."+baseRestUrl+restService+"/"+jmxConnection,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var beanRepArray = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beanRepresentation");
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: When the request is asynchronous, you have to wait for it to be sent, so put a handler in `onreadystatechanged` and check for a `readyState` of `4` and some appropriate status code. And… since when can you send the request before opening it?

Comment: sorry, yeah that was a type. it should be after open. and ill try that what you said.